# iOS app cannot be deployed on device

Tags: ios, deployment, xcode7, xcode-workspace, ios9.3

I am developing an iOS app for iPads. I have two projects inside one workspace. When I try to deploy it on the iPad, I get absolutely no error or warning and I receive the "build succeeded" message. However, the app is not deployed on the iPad. The app works just fine on the simulator without any issues.

When I first connected my iPad to my computer, I set the "trust to this computer".

I set the code signing identity to iOS developer and I selected my paid developer account in the identity section in Xcode, which made no difference.

I don't know if these are relevant but cannot think of any other solution. I would appreciate any suggestion.

I am on Xcode 7.3 and the iPad is on iOS 9.3.1, which are both the latest versions as of today.

You can see my project navigator below if it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So after you hit build, try going into your settings on your iPad. Go to General -> Device Management (almost to the bottom) -> click your email that shows up -> and see if the app is trusted in there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I didn't find any trust issue as I indicated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

After Some time, even the simulator stopped showing up. So I had to remove the existing scheme and add a new one. This resolved both the "simulator not launching" and "not being able to deploy to iPad" issues right away.

Never thought it would be this easy.